# Set format as plain text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, format, range, plaintext

```
function A1format() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var mainsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var G = mainsheet.getRange("C15:BH3000").getGridId();
 var illa = mainsheet.getRange("A13");

 Logger.log(G);
 illa.copyFormatToRange(G, 16, 3,200, 30);
 }
```

This doesnt Work and gives some strange Server error.  Please help

Comment: How doesn't it work? What error does it give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ldo Green answer above is right : in your code the end row is smaller than the start row...(columns are wrong too but it strangely accept this small negative difference) this is indeed not valid.

Using the autocomplete feature in the editor will remind you the parameters as follows :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for accepting but the other answer was first... I added mine to mention the auto complete tip. I'd suggest you mark the other one as best.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your col, colEnd and row, rowEnd values are not valid.
The format of the copyFormatToRange function is:

```
copyFormatToRange(gridId, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)

// So in your case: column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd
copyFormatToRange(G,   3,      16,      30, 200);
```

If it's not helping - please add more details about the errors you are getting and make sure that the gridId is correct.