# Force cell to be interpreted as plain text?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Following sample code gets interpreted as Date formatted cell which is not my intent. It is supposed to be plain text. Calling `clearFormat()` on the `Range` is unhelpful either.

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue("11-2");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based from this [blog](http://www.blackcj.com/blog/2015/05/18/cell-number-formatting-with-google-apps-script/), you can set the formatting of a single cell, a whole column starting from a specific cell or an entire spreadsheet. You can find additional resources on the Google Sheet [support page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470) for number formats.

```
// Use these first two lines for all four examples
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// Single cell
var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");

// Plain text
cell.setNumberFormat("@");
```

Also from this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/b-I1aLRHNvE), you can use **`range.setNumberFormat('@STRING@');`** to format cells to plain text.

Check these links:

- [Format a Google Sheets cell in plaintext via Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758913/format-a-google-sheets-cell-in-plaintext-via-apps-script)

> The other answer, to set the format to 'plain text' in javascript,
>   doesn't work. However, this does:
>
> ```
> sheet.getRange(1,n).setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
> ```
>
> So the magic value for formatting text programmatically is '@STRING@'!

- [Set format as plain text : Google SpreadSheet : Apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073939/set-format-as-plain-text-google-spreadsheet-apps-script)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This snippet saved me a lot of time ```range.setNumberFormat('@STRING@');```. Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a number when the spreadsheet parser encounters it first so it is stored as a number inside it's system.

A standard way of forcing the parser to accept anything as being text is to pre-pend the input with an apostrophe '

So your script becomes:

```
function myFunction() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue("'11-2"); 
}
```